# $_POST is working but $this->input->post empty

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have form in my `nav` template in codeigniter view

```
           <form action="<?php echo base_url()?>account/login/" class="navbar-form navbar-left" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="adres" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
                  <input type="password" name="pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>

              </form>
```

In my controller method i can `echo $_POST['adres']` and its fine, but when i try with codeigniter helper `$this->input->post('adres')` its empty . Whats wrong ?

I'm using `input->post` in my registration form and its working fine.

Comment: have you used helper class in contructor  $this->load->helper('form'); or in method

Comment: @Sebek. I have provided with the general Instructions for using the form in CI. Have a look and share thoughts regarding your view.

Answer (score 2):

### General Advice of using the forms in CodeIgnitor

**Step 1:** Try to use the native form method that are available in CI.

Syntax for Form Open:

```
form_open('[controller]/[action]')
```

Hence below is the sample example of how to open up the form based on the controller that we have created.

```
<?php echo form_open('todos/update_completed'); ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Where `todos/update_completed` means

- **todos** - Controller Name
- **update_completed** - Method name in that Controller.

  ---

**Step 2:** Load up the form elements during the auto load itself or you can load up the form elements in the Construct function itself.

> Loading the `form` attributes via the helper in the construct function.

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

Below is the example of how to call it.

```
function __construct()
{
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->helper('form'); 
}
```

**Step 3:** And in the Controller or in the model you have to get the Input that has been posted like this below.

```
$this->input->post('title')
$this->input->post('username')
```

These are all the General Checks that has to be made while using the form elements in CodeIgnitor.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used helper class in constructor `$this->load->helper('form');` or in method .

You can load helper function in your controller like this

```
function __construct()
{         
  $this->load->helper('form'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, problem solved. I was using curly brace and i should use a normal one. My bad

Comment: If then you may close this question. Problem Solved!

Comment: Your problems are not solved unless you pay attention to what Naresh posted for you. Your form is not secure